# 2D matrix into vector and index in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix as follows:

```
> td
  doc_id        d_name
1      1    John Smith
2      3  Casey Newton
3      5 Ricardo Adams
4      6  Jonah Jensen
```

I want to convert into a name vector which is indexed by its id:

```
> df
John Smith  Casey Newton Ricardo Adams  Jonah Jensen 
        1             3             5             6
```

Is there a way this is possible? Or may be a more efficient approach?

Comment: Is that a `matrix` or a `data.frame`? Not that it matters much ... `setNames(td[,1], td[,2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The simplest solution is:

```
a= td[,1]
names(a) = td[,2]
```

Comment: I knew it would be something very simple. Thanks a ton!!